# Uncaught TypeError: *.watch is not a function (except FireFox)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that there are thousands questions about this, but no one helped.

The problem is in the watch event that works fine in FireFox, but not works in other browsers.

I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Step.watch is not a function

What I need understand from this? watch works only in FireFox?

```js
function Step()
{
  this.done = false;
  this.active = false;
};
function StepsControl()
{
  this.steps = new Array();
  this.addListener = function(Step,stepId)
  {
    var self = this;
    Step.watch('done', function (id_, oldval, newval)
    {
      console.log('Step[' + stepId + '].' + id_ + ' changed from ' + oldval + ' to ' + newval);
      if (self.steps[++stepId] !== undefined)
      {
        self.steps[stepId].active = true;
        console.log('Step[' + stepId + '] actived');
      }
      
      return newval;
    });
  };
  this.addStep = function(Step)
  {
    this.steps.push(Step);
    this.addListener(Step,this.steps.length-1);
  };
};

var step1 = new Step();
var step2 = new Step();
var stepsControl = new StepsControl();
stepsControl.addStep(step1);
stepsControl.addStep(step2);
step1.active = true;
step1.done = true;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Mozilla documentation:

> Warning: Generally you should avoid using watch() and unwatch() when possible. These two methods are implemented only in Gecko, and they're intended primarily for debugging use. In addition, using watchpoints has a serious negative impact on performance, which is especially true when used on global objects, such as window. You can usually use setters and getters or proxies instead. See Browser compatibility for details. Also, do not confuse Object.watch with Object.observe.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch

Answer (score 1):

`watch` is only supported in firefox, [as can be seen when checking MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch#Browser_compatibility)